# Copy value from one column into another during insert using postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

If I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable
(
    id       SERIAL,
    content  TEXT,
    copyofid INTEGER
);
```

Is there a way to copy `id` into `copyofid` in a single insert statement?

I tried:
`INSERT INTO mytable(content, copyofid) VALUES("test", id);`

But that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: you can use a `generated column`, see the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/ddl-generated-columns.html)

Comment: I need to be able to insert with copy in some cases and not others, generated column does not seem to allow that.

Comment: So you can create a [trigger function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/sql-createtrigger.html) which is fired BEFORE INSERT of a new row intable `mytable` and which contains a test condition : `IF condition THEN NEW.copyofid = NEW.id ; END IF ;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the sequence behind your serial column using [`pg_get_serial_sequence()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-CATALOG-TABLE) and access it using [`currval()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-sequence.html#FUNCTIONS-SEQUENCE-TABLE) to get what serial column just got as a result of your `INSERT`.

```sql
CREATE TABLE mytable
(   id       SERIAL,
    content  TEXT,
    copyofid INTEGER
);

--this works for a single-record insert
INSERT INTO mytable
  (content, copyofid) 
  VALUES
  ('test', currval(pg_get_serial_sequence('mytable','id')));

--inserting more, you'll have to handle both columns relying on the sequence
INSERT INTO mytable
( id, 
  content, 
  copyofid) 
  VALUES
( nextval(pg_get_serial_sequence('mytable','id')),
  'test3', 
  currval(pg_get_serial_sequence('mytable','id'))),
( nextval(pg_get_serial_sequence('mytable','id')),
  'test4', 
  currval(pg_get_serial_sequence('mytable','id')));

table mytable;
-- id | content | copyofid
------+---------+----------
--  1 | test    |        1
--  2 | test3   |        2
--  3 | test4   |        3
--(3 rows)
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/4G6nauaH)

[Edouard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8060017/edouard) makes [makes a fair point](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74199766/5298879) that if you can specify the conditions when you want this behaviour, you can add them to the definition:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable
(   id       SERIAL,
    content  TEXT,
    copyofid integer 
        generated always as (
        case when content ilike '%requires copying ID%' then id end)
        stored
);
insert into mytable (content) values ('abc') returning *;
-- id | content | copyofid
------+---------+----------
--  1 | abc     |
--(1 row)
insert into mytable (content) values ('abc, but requires copying ID') returning *;
-- id |           content            | copyofid
------+------------------------------+----------
--  2 | abc, but requires copying ID |        2
--(1 row)
```

If they vary between inserts

```sql
CREATE TABLE mytable                                                                                                                
(   id       SERIAL,
    content  TEXT,
    copyofid integer
        generated always as (
        case when should_copy_id then id end)
        stored,
    should_copy_id boolean default false
);
insert into mytable (content) values ('efg') returning *;
-- id | content | copyofid | should_copy_id
------+---------+----------+----------------
--  1 | efg     |          | f
--(1 row)
insert into mytable (content,should_copy_id) values ('klm','today'::date<>'2022-10-28'::date) returning *;
-- id | content | copyofid | should_copy_id
------+---------+----------+----------------
--  2 | klm     |        2 | t
--(1 row)
```

The trigger will be better if

1. the check is fairly complex - generated columns are pretty limited in terms of the definition complexity. For example, you can't use [mutable](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-volatility.html) functions in them - not even `STABLE` are accepted
2. you want to save the logic and change it later without having to drop the column each time, then re-add it with a new definition (only way to alter a generated column definition)
3. as a part of the `insert` you'll want to do more than just copy the id column

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to create a trigger function which is fired before inserting a new row in table mytable and which copy NEW.id into NEW.copyofid if a condition is true :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION before_insert_mytable() RETURN trigger LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
BEGIN
  IF condition
  THEN NEW.copyofid = NEW.id ;
  END IF ;
  RETURN NEW ;
END ; $$

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER before_insert_mytable BEFORE INSERT ON mytable
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION before_insert_mytable () ;
```

The condition can also be stated directly in the `WHEN` clause of the trigger instead of in the function :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION before_insert_mytable() RETURN trigger LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
BEGIN
  NEW.copyofid = NEW.id ;
  RETURN NEW ;
END ; $$

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER before_insert_mytable BEFORE INSERT ON mytable
WHEN condition
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION before_insert_mytable () ;
```

see the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/sql-createtrigger.html)